# Precision of ratio constraint in a linear program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, constrained-optimization, linear-programming

I am trying to solve a LP in which one of my constraints is of the form

$$\frac{A(x)}{B(x)} = 1$$

I transform this constraint into a linear one

$$A(x) - B(x) = 0$$

However when CPLEX solves the problem, this constraint is of the order of ~1.e-5, but the ratio is of the order of ~1.4, which is a large deviation for my needs. Unfortunately the kappa value (condition number of the optimal basis) of the problem is kappa ~10^10, and this doesn't make things easier. I suspect this is the source of the problem.

**My question**: is it possible (given the value of kappa) to increase the precision of this constraint such as the ratio to be accurate within 2 decimal digits (at least) ~ 1.00something ?

Comment: How are functions $A$ and $B$ defined?

Comment: Ask your question at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000002059 . That forum has the top CPLEX experrts  in the world (IBM CPLEX employees and power users). Have you looked at the scaling in your problem?  It is apparently horrible, so the question is whether it can be improved. When you post at the CPLEX forum, attach your model so people can look a it and provide specific advice rather than generalities.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thank you, I'll giver it a try in the IBM forum. I am not sure exactly how I can achieve scaling is in the LP terminology. I've scaled all of my functions to be in the order [0,1], this improved things slightly. Is there some reference for scaling in LP problems? To give some more idea, the problem is an astronomy problem, where I have linearised equations of a dynamical system, that is subject to constraints - great similarity with FEM methods.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you, A(x) and B(x) are linear functions of the unknown vector values x, say A(x) = \sum_i x_i W_i, where W_i are constants resulting from single or double numerical integrals (GL quadrature).

Comment: As I wrote, Provide your model as attachment(s) to your CPLEX forum post. if you do''t, someone will probably request it.

Comment: I have scaled my problem, and now the ratio is accurate within ~1e-8 decimal digits, despite the ill conditioning being persistent. Super cool,  thank you all for the help.